# How to plot a 3d scatterplot with the color determined from another variable?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I made a 3d scatterplot that displays the position of galaxies in a cluster (basically like the latitude and longitude) as a function of their velocity.  However, I've been asked to make the color of the data points be determined by another variable, h in the code.  The purpose of the variable isn't important to know, but that in my actual code, every data point is determined from 4 arrays.  After spending a long time looking up how to do this, I finally (almost) have it.  The only problem is that when I plot it, the colors of the dots change as soon as I move the plot around to see it from a different direction.  Also, I've been having issues trying to display a colorbar.

```
import pylab as p
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ra=np.random.random((100))
dec=np.random.random((100))
h=np.random.random((100))
z=np.random.random((100))

datamin=min(h)
datamax=max(h)
fig=p.figure()

ax3D=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3D.scatter(ra, dec, z, c=h, vmin=datamin, vmax=datamax, 
marker='o', cmap=cm.Spectral)

p.title("MKW4s-Position vs Velocity")
p.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

'Changing color upon redraw' issue was a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/152) but looks like it's fixed in the latest release (1.1.1). I've tested and confirmed that it's working as it should with 1.1.1.

For the `colorbar`, it needs a mappable. You can use the collection returned from `scatter`:

```
import pylab as p
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

ra=np.random.random((100))
dec=np.random.random((100))
h=np.random.random((100))
z=np.random.random((100))

datamin=min(h)
datamax=max(h)
fig=p.figure()

ax3D=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
collection = ax3D.scatter(ra, dec, z, c=h, vmin=datamin, vmax=datamax, 
                          marker='o', cmap=cm.Spectral)
p.colorbar(collection)

p.title("MKW4s-Position vs Velocity")
p.show()
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I deleted the old one and downloaded the new one and it still isn't working.  When I reposition they all turn blue.  The colormap looks great though, thanks!  edit: Nevermind I'm an idiot.